# Timechecking: Server side or Client side?

Tags: javascript, client-server

I'm developing a quiz like application.
This application tracks how much time does the user takes to answer every single question.

Should I count time server side or client side?

I came up with this pros/cons:

Server Side:
**pros:** user cannot "cheat"
**cons:** user latency can heavily impact

Client Side:
**pros:** time tracking is more precise
**cons:** a semi-expert user can use some javascript to "cheat"

By desing, changing the logic behind (ie: calculating an average time per answer) would break the purpouse of the application.

Latency can be an issue, since a variation of 5-10 seconds can change the user's final score (multiply it for an average of 50 answers); this application can run on smartphone and tablet, so high I'm expecting high network latency.

I think this can be a general html5/javascript developing problem, but for who's asking, I'm using node.js as server.

Answer (score 0):

If the quiz application is not sensitive then just use the client side's time.

If it is very time sensitive, I would use both the server and client side's time.

If the client side's time is less than that of the server by a large amount of time (say 5 seconds), then it is safe to assume the client was cheating.

---

Also, I should warn you that if the answer to the questions are constant, it is quite easy to create a script which will auto-fill the values.

Eg.
`document.getElementById("QuestionOne").value="TheCorrectAnswer";void(0)`;

Answer (score 0):

You can use client side time,and compare it with server side time,i.e using both.It wont need much code,but will be safe.